# How can I pick a random enum when everyone has different probabilities?

Tags: java, random, enums

I know here in stackoverflow there is already a question about how to randomly select an enum. In the example code, every letter has the same probability of being selected. But how would I rewrite the code when not every enum has the same probability? For example: A has a probability of 50%, B of 30%, C of 15% and D of 5%.

```
public enum Letter {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D;

  private static final List<Letter> VALUES =
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
  private static final int SIZE = VALUES.size();
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public static Letter randomLetter()  {
    return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));
  }
}
```

Comment: Make an array with length of 20, put 1 D, 3 C, 6 B and 10 A in it. Then get a random number from 0 to 19 and get an array element with this index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way associating each enum value with a probability range, then fitting a random number in the range to select a value:

```
enum Letter {
    A(0, 51), B(51, 81), C(81, 96), D(95, 101);

    private int probStart;
    private int probEnd;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    Letter(int s, int e) {
        this.probStart = s;
        this.probEnd = e;
    }

    public static Letter randomLetter() {
        int pick = RANDOM.nextInt(100);
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(v -> pick >= v.probStart && pick < v.probEnd)
                .findAny()
                .get();
    }
}
```

Of course you can choose to cache these *probabilities* in a map, but an implementation like the one above (based on percent scales) may just seem to create too large a map for the search to be undesirable.

A few tests produced successively these sets of 100 selections:

```
{A=56, B=26, C=14, D=4}
{A=39, B=39, C=18, D=4}
{A=51, B=30, C=13, D=6}
```

Comment: This is a bit error-prone, since the developer has to make sure that the ranges are continuous without gaps and non-overlapping ... it would be safer to just store the weight with each enum and then calculate all the ranges and the max value internally. I.e. `A(50), B(30), C(15), D(5)`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, making values declare a probability is definitely less error-prone, but the same class (developer) would be responsible for normalizing probabilities

Comment: @ernest_k thank you for your help! one question: why is there a gap between 0 and 51 and not 0 and 50 or 1 and 51 (same thing between 95 and 101)?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/osdi/full_papers/waldspurger.pdf can help you

specifically this image:
[image]

In your example, choose a number `x` between `0` and `99`

- `x < 50` ==> A wins
- `50 <= x < 80` ==> B wins
- `80 <= x < 95` ==> C wins
- `95 <= x` ==> D wins